# R - Compare and test primary data frame on multiple conditions with secondary data frame and if true assign a given value from secondary data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, testing, dplyr, lubridate

I have two data frames which the following code will provide an example of the data that I have:

```
df <- data.frame("ID" = c(325, 464, 464, 464, 464, 464, 464, 464, 464, 464, 512, 512, 687, 701, 869), 
             "DATE" = c("2012-11-05", "2014-04-04", "2014-04-05", "2014-04-06", "2015-01-25", 
                        "2015-01-25", "2015-01-26", "2015-01-26", "2015-01-26", "2015-01-27", 
                        "2014-10-13", "2014-10-14", "2014-12-12", "2015-02-17", "2015-06-25"))

df2 <- data.frame("ID" = c(325, 464, 464, 512, 701, 869, 922, 954, 989),
              "DATE_1" = c("2012-11-03", "2014-04-01", "2015-01-20", "2014-10-10", "2015-02-14",
                           "2015-06-20", "2015-07-07", "2015-09-11", "2015-11-23"),

              "DATE_2" = c("2012-11-08", "2014-04-10", "2015-01-29", "2014-10-19", "2015-02-22",
                           "2015-06-29", "2015-07-13", "2015-09-25", "2015-11-29"),

              "INTERVAL" = c("2012-11-03--2012-08-11 UTC", "2014-04-01--2014-04-10 UTC",
                             "2015-01-20--2015-01-29 UTC", "2014-10-10--2014-10-19 UTC", 
                             "2015-02-14--2014-02-22 UTC", "2015-06-20--2015-06-29 UTC", 
                             "2015-07-07--2015-07-13 UTC", "2015-09-11--2015-09-25 UTC", 
                             "2015-11-23--2015-11-29 UTC"),
              "KEY" = c(6, 8, 92, 233, 642, 1233, 2464, 3436, 4366))
```

Which should yield:

```
    df
    ID       DATE
1  325 2012-11-05
2  464 2014-04-04
3  464 2014-04-05
4  464 2014-04-06
5  464 2015-01-25
6  464 2015-01-25
7  464 2015-01-26
8  464 2015-01-26
9  464 2015-01-26
10 464 2015-01-27
11 512 2014-10-13
12 512 2014-10-14
13 687 2014-12-12
14 701 2015-02-17
15 869 2015-06-25



   df2
   ID     DATE_1     DATE_2                   INTERVAL  KEY
1 325 2012-11-03 2012-11-08 2012-11-03--2012-08-11 UTC    6
2 464 2014-04-01 2014-04-10 2014-04-01--2014-04-10 UTC    8
3 464 2015-01-20 2015-01-29 2015-01-20--2015-01-29 UTC   92
4 512 2014-10-10 2014-10-19 2014-10-10--2014-10-19 UTC  233
5 701 2015-02-14 2015-02-22 2015-02-14--2014-02-22 UTC  642
6 869 2015-06-20 2015-06-29 2015-06-20--2015-06-29 UTC 1233
7 922 2015-07-07 2015-07-13 2015-07-07--2015-07-13 UTC 2464
8 954 2015-09-11 2015-09-25 2015-09-11--2015-09-25 UTC 3436
9 989 2015-11-23 2015-11-29 2015-11-23--2015-11-29 UTC 4366
```

The interval column was created with lubridate's interval function with "DATE_1" and "DATE_2" as arguments embedded in dplyr's mutate function.

My problem is that I need to test the rows in my primary data.frame (df) if the ID matches the ID in my secondary data.frame (df2) and if the date in df falls within the interval in df2.

I would like R to create a new column in df called "NEW_KEY" and if a row in df tests true under both conditions then R should take the value in the KEY column in df2 from the row in which fit on ID and interval and insert it into the NEW_KEY column in df. If the row tests false under both conditions then R should insert NA in the row under the NEW_KEY column.

Do mind that df contains multiple duplicates which all should tests true under both conditions and should have the same KEY value filled in each row and df also contains ID which has no corresponding row in df2 and should have its NEW_KEY filled with NA.

I have attempted the following two simplistic code

```
df$NEW_KEY <- ifelse(ifelse(df$ID %in% df2$ID & df$DATE %within% df2$INTERVAL, df2$KEY, NA)
```

and

```
df <- mutate(df, NEW_VALUE = ifelse(df$ID %in% df2$ID & df$DATE %within% df2$INTERVAL, df2$KEY, NA))
```

both which yield the same error message:

```
1: I as.numeric(a) - as.numeric(int@start) : longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
2: I as.numeric(a) - as.numeric(int@start) <= int@.Data : longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
3: I as.numeric(a) - as.numeric(int@start) : longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

and only seems to fill out some rows in df and NA the rest.

So I'm currently at a halt on what to do. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:** ID 464 has two different intervals (in 2014 and 2015) in df2 with corresponding dates in df which falls either within one or the other interval in df2. When I do a merge, R does not seem to distinguish so some rows will be a mix of the two - in the way that some rows in df will have 2014 under the DATE column, but the Interval column (merged from df2) is the interval from 2015 instead of 2014.

Answer (score 0):

does this help ?

`library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df <- merge(df, df2, by = "ID", all.x = TRUE)
df <-  df %>% mutate(DATE = as.Date(DATE),DATE_1 = as.Date(DATE_1), DATE_2 = as.Date(DATE_2) )
df %>% mutate(NEW_VALUE = ifelse(DATE %within% (DATE_1 %--% DATE_2) , KEY, NA))`

Comment: Unfortunately, I oversimplified the example and omitted a crucial detail - some IDs are also duplicated in df2 with a different interval (e.g. an ID in a row with the interval in 2014 and another row with the same ID but the interval in 2015 in df2 and df contains both rows with dates in 2014 and 2015). When I attempt to merge df and df2, R does not seem to distinguish so I end up with some rows which are a mix (date in 2014 and interval in 2015 and would thus yield a false negative because it should have the 2014-interval instead). The code in OP has been edited. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Either you able to identify, or you are not. If you are, the way you do it in your head could be put in the machine .. no ? Maybe you could add a column with the year in each table, or you can split the fist table by year ..

Comment: I was able to get around the error message with the code "df <- mutate(df, NEW_VALUE = ifelse(df$ID %in% df2$ID & inrange(df$DATE, df2$DATE_1, df2$DATE_2), df2$KEY, NA))" and R seems to do the test properly. The only problem is that R does not seem to fill out the correct value if a row has been tested true when it encounters a duplicate. Instead of filling out with value in KEY value from the row which matched in df2, R seems to cycle through the available KEY values instead of grabbing the same KEY value if two rows in df tested true for a single row in df2.